# Secure Graphite installation

Tags: authentication, graphite

I think I misunderstand something here. I've installed Graphite with Docker (sitespeedio/graphite) and set a Basic Auth for the Web-Panel. I opened the Firwall for Port 2003 to get in datapoints from other servers and it worked fine.

But there is no authentication/authorisation. Even the python lib I used to send some tests does not allow to set a password, token or other authentication mechanism.

How to I secure my Graphite installation?

Answer (score 4):

I think there may be a misunderstanding (quite possibly on my part): you seem to be talking about two different components.

The first is Graphite (https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html):

> Graphite renders graphs using the Cairo graphics library

In other words, while we usually call the whole setup graphite, graphite is actually the front-end to the database carbon stores data in (Whisper or Ceres).

Basic-Auth, as you say, is for the web interfaces graphite offers, notably the render API (and more generally, services the graphite process/daemon offers over HTTP).

To put that in place (generally - I don't know the details for your specific situation), you could check this question: [Graphiti / Graphite using Apache with Proxy and BasicAuth requests auth for every URL / request](https://serverfault.com/questions/459317/graphiti-graphite-using-apache-with-proxy-and-basicauth-requests-auth-for-ever) - they have the opposite issue where they *have* to authenticate constantly (and an answer about why that might be).

They provide their full config, but in general, the following block is what matters:

```
 <Location "/">
          require valid-user
          order allow,deny
          Allow from all
          AuthType Basic
          AuthName "Stats"
          AuthBasicProvider file
          AuthUserFile /etc/passwd_lp
  </Location>
```

However, you also mention port 2003, which is not related to any of the web APIs or pages.

Port 2003 is instead used by carbon-cache (or carbon-relay), to receive metric data.

Per https://graphite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/carbon-daemons.html:

> carbon-cache.py accepts metrics over various protocols and writes them to disk as efficiently as possible

It does not use HTTP, which is why Basic-Auth is not working.

I am not sure what best-practice or convention is for securing carbon, but I had always thought it was a matter of restricting access to the service (i.e. port) in the first place.

You could add a layer that spoke HTTP between your metric sources, and your carbon-cache, in order to have Basic Auth in place for it.

You could also add something like HAProxy to do SSL termination and client validation, but I am not sure how easy it would be to make metric sources use SSL/TLS in the first place.